# Configuring Spring Scheduler At run time based on db values

Tags: spring, scheduler

I have Spring scheduler which reads configuration from property file. I need to read this configuration from database instead.

Given below is the structure for scheduler

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 2000, fixedDelayString = "${value for first        
 taskfrom db}")
 public void doFirsttask() {
    //do sceduled task
}

 @Scheduled(initialDelay = 2000, fixedDelayString = "${value from      
  second task from db}")
 public void doSecondtask() {
    //do sceduled task
 }
```

What is the possible way to set this up ?
Also is it possible to reschedule things on run time if the values get changed in the db?

Comment: did you get any solution for this... I also need to get the scheduler timings from database

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to do that from code rather than from annotations. The Spring [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) are a good source of information for this.

In your code, you'll need to build a `Runnable` and then pass it to the `Scheduler` together with a trigger. For example

```
TaskScheduler scheduler = //get instance from Spring;
scheduler.schedule(runnableWithYourTask, new PeriodicTrigger(/* whatever you need here*/));
```

You might need to have a Spring bean that listens for the `ContextStartedEvent` event and

- queries the DB to get the period.
- schedules the tasks. (You might want to keep a reference to the ScheduledFuture in case you want to cancel tasks)